# Simulate click on SAVE button

Tags: excel, vba

I run a vba sub routine which creates a PDF file - and all works, the only issue I now have is that I do not want the user to have to click on the save button and want to simulate this in VBA. My code is as follows"

```
Fname = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(ws.Name & "_" & Range("M21") & "_" & _
            VBA.Strings.Format(Now, "ddmmyy"), filefilter:=FileFormatstr, _
            Title:="Create PDF")
```

Not to sure what and where I need to add the code to force the save

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why simulate a click? Just have it save as pdf in the code direct.

Comment: Hi, because I email individual and in batch - so individual I want them to click save, but in batch it must just save it and move to the next email - hope that makes sense

Comment: So does your code know if this is a batch? If yes, use a conditional in your code to either use SaveAs, or not. Same way you'd decide whether the code should *click the button*.

Comment: so if I get this correctly, all I need to do is change my code to        Fname = Application.SaveAsFilename(ws.Name & "_" & Range("M21") & "_" & _
            VBA.Strings.Format(Now, "ddmmyy"), filefilter:=FileFormatstr, _
            Title:="Create PDF")

Comment: Have a look through some of these https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=save+file+as+pdf+vba&oq=save+file+as+pdf+vba&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4691j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

The code that you have uses ***GetSaveAsFilename*** and this is the [official document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195748(v=office.11).aspx) of it & if you read the first line in the document it will state the functionality which is - *Displays the standard Save As dialog box and gets a file name from the user without actually saving any files.*

But what you are trying to do is Save the file automatically without showing the dialog box in the form of a PDF.Therefore, you need to use ***ExportAsFixedFormat*** and this is the [official document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-exportasfixedformat-method-excel) of it.

So, you can use something like this:-

```
ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF FileName:="sales.pdf" Quality:=xlQualityStandard DisplayFileAfterPublish:=True
```

And to answer your case, you will need an if else loop on your program to switch between both of your cases.